# Cannot importing facebook sdk into my android project

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I have imported and added the facebook sdk for my android  project. But in my project under gen folder, then under com.facebook.android folder I get only R.java file. Please help me to get this solved.

Comment: that's how it should be. what's the problem you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

You have to import it into your workspace and configure it as a library (  Properties/Android/Library Is Library checked)

then import it into your project under Properties/Android/Library Add the facebook project

Check that the facebook project is in your build path Properties/ Java Build Path/ Projects

And then you should see it under Android Dependencies

Comment: I didnt see it initially but after I added that project folder it says cannot find facebook.apk

Answer (score -1):

You can do it the other way round, instead of importing the facebook library just copy the entire package com.facebook.android into your project.... Thats it.... no need to import any thing.....